# python http handler

Tags: python, http, request, handler

I want something like [`BaseHTTPRequestHandler`](http://docs.python.org/library/basehttpserver.html#BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler), except that I don't want it to bind to any sockets; I want to handle the raw HTTP data to and from it myself.  Is there a good way that I can do this in Python?

To Clarify, I want a class that receives raw TCP data from Python (NOT a socket), processes it and returns TCP data as a response (to python again).  So this class will handle TCP handshaking, and will have methods that override what I send on HTTP GET and POST, like `do_GET` and `do_POST`.  So, I want something like the Server infrastructure that already exists, except I want to pass *all raw TCP packets* in python and not through operating system sockets.

Answer (score 3):

`BaseHTTPRequestHandler` derives from `StreamRequestHandler`, which basically reads from file `self.rfile` and writes to `self.wfile`, so you can derive a class from `BaseHTTPRequestHandler` and supply your own rfile and wfile e.g.

```
import StringIO
from  BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler

class MyHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def __init__(self, inText, outFile):
        self.rfile = StringIO.StringIO(inText)
        self.wfile = outFile
        BaseHTTPRequestHandler.__init__(self, "", "", "")

    def setup(self):
        pass

    def handle(self):
        BaseHTTPRequestHandler.handle(self)

    def finish(self):
        BaseHTTPRequestHandler.finish(self)

    def address_string(self):
        return "dummy_server"

    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write("<html><head><title>WoW</title></head>")
        self.wfile.write("<body><p>This is a Total Wowness</p>")
        self.wfile.write("</body></html>")

outFile = StringIO.StringIO()

handler = MyHandler("GET /wow HTTP/1.1", outFile)
print ''.join(outFile.buflist)
```

**Output:**

```
dummy_server - - [15/Dec/2009 19:22:24] "GET /wow HTTP/1.1" 200 -
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Server: BaseHTTP/0.3 Python/2.5.1
Date: Tue, 15 Dec 2009 13:52:24 GMT
Content-type: text/html

<html><head><title>WoW</title></head><body><p>This is a Total Wowness</p></body></html>
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  However, I really want to give it RAW TCP data, and get the raw TCP data response back.

Comment: why don't you write your own tcp server, twisted(http://twistedmatrix.com/) might help or may be answer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581087/python-tcp-stack-implementation

Comment: also see http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/introduction.html?highlight=syn

Comment: This is indeed 'Total Wowness'